# Documentation for python

Tags: filetype-python

I've been looking around for a while now but I couldn't find a proper answer.

I would like to access python documentation from Vim. I know that some plugins exist (like this one: https://github.com/fs111/pydoc.vim). But these plugins are far from perfect. WIth pydoc for example, if you press K on a word, you'll get the documentation.

E.g:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

If you <kbd>K</kbd> on `pyplot`, you'll get the documentation.
But if you have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

If <kbd>K</kbd> on `plt`, you won't get anything.

There is also the jedi plugin, which displays documentation on the fly. If you type `plt.`, it will display the objects/methods of `plt`. But you need to be typing for that.

Also, I think none of these plugins work on the code present in the same folder but imported in the current file. For example, if `my_module` is implemented in a folder, and if I import it in `my_script.py`, I don't have access to the documentation from `my_module`.

Do you have any idea how to improve my situation please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using [jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) which can show the documentation for modules and functions. By default, it uses `K` to look up documentation.

Since it relies on [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi), you must install Jedi package first:

```
pip install jedi
# or conda install jedi
```